# Cierre inesperado del programa al usar qTbaleview en QT c++ por el evento de doble clic

Tags: c++, qt-creator, uitableview

Estoy haciendo un programa sencillo para la gestión de los datos de empleados usando **SQLITE** como base de datos.

Tengo una **Qtableview** donde se muestran los datos de todos los empleados y quiero que al dar doble clic sobre una de sus celdas se actualicen unos **line_edit** con los datos que corresponden al empleado en cuestion.

El problema es que al dar doble clic se cierra el programa y no emite ningun error. He comprobado que es la sentencia específca para preparar la consulta la que causa esto, comentando todo lo demás. Pero no se como resolver este problema.

```
<code>

        void EmployeInfo::on_tableView_doubleClicked(QModelIndex index)
    {
        Login conn;// calse para abrir y cerrar conexion con la bd
        QSqlQuery *qry = new QSqlQuery(conn.mydb);//mydb es mi base de datos
    
        QString val = ui->tableView->model()->data(index).toString();//sin usar por ahora
    
    
        if(!conn.connOpen())
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Eror SQL:"), "No se pudo abrir la base de datos");
        }
    
    
         qry->prepare("SELECT * from employeinfo WHERE id =1");
    
       /* if(qry->exec())
        {
            while(qry->next())
            {
                ui->text_eid->setText(qry->value(0).toString());
                ui->text_name->setText(qry->value(1).toString());
                ui->text_surname->setText(qry->value(2).toString());
                ui->text_year->setText(qry->value(3).toString().section('.',0,3));
                ui->text_month->setText(qry->value(3).toString().section('.',4,5));
                ui->text_fecha_day->setText(qry->value(3).toString().section('.',6,7));
                ui->text_direccion->setText(qry->value(4).toString());
                ui->text_telefono->setText(qry->value(5).toString());
    
    
            }
            conn.connClose();//cierra la conexion con la base de datos
    
        }
        else
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("Error SQL:"),qry->lastError().text());
        }
    
    */
    
    }
</code>
```

Comment: Yo evitaría usar `new` en este caso. Evita usar memoria dinámica cuando no sea necesario (y en este caso no lo es). También podrías probar a aislar la llamada a `prepare` con un `try-catch` para ver si se lanza alguna excepción. Por otro lado, no tiene demasiado sentido que primero crees la query y luego compruebes si la conexión está abierta (quizás deberías hacerlo al revés)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tus suegerencias, las implementé pero el error persiste. La memoria dinámica la usé para probar si arreglaba algo milagrosamente pero no fue así y ahora volví a la estática. de otra forma ya que nunca pude dar con la solucion a este problema. solo uso el evento doble clic para obtener el index y realizo la consulta con un push_boton. Aunque no es elegante funciona.

Comment: Podría ser que el error tuviese que ver con `conn`. Declaras la variable, luego se invoca algún constructor, pero puede que ese objeto realice alguna operación de forma incorrecta. Prueba a no cargar `conn` en la query